# Find linear transformation matrix for basis of $\mathbb R_2$, that projects every vector vertically on $y=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Basis of $\mathbb R_2$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
if i guesed it right. I found this expression for orthogonal projection in my math book and don't know how to use it
 $A= \frac 1{||\vec u||}\begin{bmatrix} u_x^2 & u_x u_y \\ u_x u_y & u_y^2 \end{bmatrix}, \vec{u} = (u_x, u_y)$. I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2):

The linear transformation $P$ that projects every vector vertically on $y=0$ is given by

$P(x,y)=(x,0)$. Since $P(1,0)=(1,0)$ and $P(0,1)=(0,0)$ we get the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$.